# Android Help! null pointer and problems with code

Tags: java, android

i'm coding an application for college and one of the activities sends (on button click) banking information saved in preferences via SMS and email in the background.. Currently the email will send but information saved in preferences will arrive with null value:

send email method:

```
public synchronized void sendMail(String loc, String sender, String recipients) throws Exception {   
    try{
    MimeMessage message = new MimeMessage(session);   
    //loc = loc.replace(" ", "");
    String mes = "Help!! I've completely run out of money and need you to send some via bank transfer please. "
            + "my account info is: "
            + BankNameAddress
            + " "
            + " account number: "
            + BankAccount
            + " Sort Code is: "
            + SortCode
            + " "
            + "Thank you so much!!";
    DataHandler handler = new DataHandler(new ByteArrayDataSource(mes.getBytes(), "text/plain"));   
    message.setSender(new InternetAddress(sender));   
    message.setSubject("Help Money Emergency!");   
    message.setDataHandler(handler); 
    addAttachment(mes);
    message.setContent(_multipart);
    if (recipients.indexOf(',') > 0)   
        message.setRecipients(Message.RecipientType.TO, InternetAddress.parse(recipients));   
    else  
        message.setRecipient(Message.RecipientType.TO, new InternetAddress(recipients));   
    Transport.send(message);   
    }catch(Exception e){

    }
}
```

preferences java:

```
package com.attack.android;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.preference.PreferenceActivity;

public class Prefs extends PreferenceActivity{

    @SuppressWarnings("deprecation")
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        addPreferencesFromResource(R.xml.prefs);
    }

}
```

preferences xml:

```
<EditTextPreference
    android:key="BankAccount"
    android:summary="Enter your bank account number"
    android:title="Bank account Number" >
</EditTextPreference>
<EditTextPreference
    android:key="BankNameAddress"
    android:summary="Enter your banks name and address"
    android:title="Bank name and address" >
</EditTextPreference>
<EditTextPreference
    android:key="SortCode"
    android:summary="Enter your bank sort code"
    android:title="Sort Code" >
</EditTextPreference>
```

Comment: Post your logcat output please.

Comment: First of all, do not send sensitive info in String format, use char[] instead, it is safer.

Comment: How are you retrieving data from the preferences?

Answer (score 0):

I think you aren't populating your preference values correctly. Here's how you are supposed to do it.

```
SharedPreferences prefs = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(context);
String bankAccount=prefs.getString("BankAccount","");
...
```

The first value is the key from your preferences, the second is the default value, in case nothing was previously entered.

Also, as a matter of style, only classes should start with an uppercase, variables should start with a lowercase. It just makes it easier to figure out what's happening. `BankAccount` is one such example.